# CloudFormation template not updating after CDK deployment

Tags: swagger, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have a generated Swagger json file. I have a CDK app that reads in this file and then I do

```
const cfnRestApi = this.api.node.defaultChild as apigateway.CfnRestApi;

cfnRestApi.body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(swaggerDefinition));
```

After doing cdk deploy when I look at the Cloud Formation template it contains my Swagger info. However when I make changes to the Swagger json file, the template in CloudFormation is not updating even after cdk deploy runs successfully. How can I resolve this?

Comment: how do you set the variable `swaggerDefinition`?

Answer (score 0):

I would move the reading of `swaggerDefinition` file to `bin/myapp.ts` and adding an extra parameter to your stack interface. Something like this:

```js
// ===>>> this is in the bin/myapp.ts
const swaggerDefinition = // read swagger file

new MyAppStack(app, 'MyAppStack', {
  swaggerDefinition,
});


// ===>>> now your lib/myapp.ts
export interface MyAppStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  swaggerDefinition: string; // or whatever type you think it needs
}

export class MyAppStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: MyAppStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    ...
    // now you can use it freely in cdk code
```

The reason behind it is that you can't really count on the order of the promises once you are in a cdk construct, but you can do whatever you want on the bin side in a more predictable manner.